# Наибольшая общая возрастающая последовательность

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Имеется задача. Найти наибольшую общую возрастающую последовательность среди двух последовательностей длинной n и m. Я написал алгоритм за O(n^2), но мне сказали, что существует решение за O(n). Жду помощи! Если укажите направление движение, будет тоже хорошо. Алгоритм должен быть реализован на С++ в виде ф-и.

Answer (score 6):

Более общая [задача](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) нахождения наибольшей общей подпоследовательности (для случая двух последовательностей) решается динамическим программированием за O(N*M).

Родственная [задача](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) нахождения наибольшей общей подстроки в двух строках (алфавит ограничен) решается суффиксными деревьями за O(N+M).

Думаю истина где-то рядом). По идее нужно использовать условие возрастания подпоследовательности.

Также стоит посмотреть на суффиксные деревья.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что где-то здесь вкралась ошибка или неточность формулировки. Даже задача нахождения наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности одной данной последовательности [решается](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_поиска_наибольшей_увеличивающейся_подпоследовательности) в общем случае за O(n log n), а тут требуется за O(n + m) найти наибольшую общую такую подпоследовательность для 
пары последовательностей?

Может быть, имелись в виду всё-таки подстроки? Если исходные последовательности возрастают, то решение уже было приведено. Если нет, то можно поделить их на возрастающие участки (ответ не может пересекать границу таких участков) и попробовать достичь нужной асимптотики (не знаю, получится ли). Также можно действительно применить суффиксные деревья, точнее, [этот](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree) алгоритм. Вроде бы, его несложно модифицировать для возрастающих подстрок, идя только по возрастающим путям в дереве.

Comment: Задача нахождения наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности одной данной последовательности решается за O(n).

Comment: Боюсь, мне такой алгоритм не известен, и я даже уверен, что для данной задачи лучшая оценка, которую я встречал, именно O(n log(n)). Не могли бы вы привести ссылку на решение за O(n)?

Comment: Ссылки у меня нет. Я ее когда-то решал. У меня есть решение. Если Вы зададите вопрос, на вроде - как решить задачу о нахождения наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности одной данной последовательности за O(n), я обязательно выложу код.Все таки, в данном вопросе обсуждается другая задача.

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось решить только за O(n^2). Думаю, намного быстрее не получится.
вот код

```
int comlen( char *p, char *q) {
    int maxlen = 0;
    while ( (*p != '\0' || *q != '\0' ) && *p++ == *q++)
         ++maxlen;
    return maxlen;
}
int isInc( char *p, int len) {
    int i = 1;
    int k = 0;
    for (; *p != '\0' && i < len; ++i, ++k) {
         if (p[i]<p[k])
         return 0;
     }
     return 1;
}
int lcis(char * str1, char * str2, int len) {
    int maxlen = -1;
    int thislen = -1;
    int maxi = 0, maxj = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
           thislen = comlen( &str1[i], &str2[j]);
               if (isInc(&str1[i], thislen)){
                   if (thislen > maxlen) {
                       maxlen = thislen; 
                       maxi = i;
                       maxj = j;
                   }
               }
         }
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

Comment: Быть может, всё-таки за O(n^3)? Два вложенных цикла + вызов comlen, который осуществляет линейный поиск. Пример: 2 строки из символов 'a' длины n.

Comment: Опечатка. Да в худшем случае время будет порядка O(n^3), а в среднем O(n^2). Можно добавить условие выхода из цикла, к примеру, когда обе строки одинаковые (сравнить текущею длину с длиной мин. строки).

Answer (score 0):

Есть алгоритм 0(n~m). Что-то между n и m.
Смысл такой:

- есть глобальные итераторы (или указатели) на:

  - начало в первой последовательности, первоначально = 0
  - начало во второй последовательности, первоначально = 0
  - длина последовательности, первоначально = 0
- текущие переменные
- начало в первой последовательности, первоначально = 0 // всегда равны 0, если мы не находимся в общей подпоследовательности
- начало во второй последовательности, первоначально = 0 // всегда равны 0, если мы не находимся в общей подпоследовательности
- длинна последовательности, первоначально = 0
- есть какие-то текущие указатели и условие цикла

```
   for (iterator i1 = listN.begin(), iterator i2=listM.begin(); i1!=listN.end() && i2!=listM.end(); )
   {
       if (мы не в общей подпоследовательности)
       {
          if (*il=*i2)
          {
             то начинаем новую подпоседовательность, заодно длина текущей подпоследовательности ++;
             ++i1;
             ++i2;
          }
          else
          {
             сдвигаем тот итератор, значение по которому меньше;
          }
       }
       else if (мы в общей подпоследовательности)
       {
          if (*il=*i2)
          {
             длина текущей подпоследовательности ++;
             ++i1;
             ++i2;
          }
          else
          {
             общая подпоследовательность закончилась,
             сравниваем ее с найденной глобальной; 
             если текущая больше глобальной, приравниваем глобальную текущей;
             ставим текущие начала последовательности в NULL, 
             а текущую длину подпоследоваельности в 0;
             сдвигаем тот итератор, значение по которому меньше;
          }
       }
   }
```

После прохода цикла в глобальных переменных будет лежать результат: если подпоследовательность была,
тут итерируется либо оба итератора, если значения по ним равны, либо 1 из них, по которому значение больше, до тех пор пока, не достигнут конец одного из списков.

Comment: Во-первых, это похоже на алгоритм поиска общей возрастающей подстроки, а не подпоследовательности (в подпоследовательности не обязательно элементы были соседними в исходной последовательности). Во-вторых, он вроде бы не всегда находит наибольший ответ. Пример: [9, 1, 2, 3] и [1, 2, 3, 9], он найдёт [9]. Вроде бы, он работает в том случае, если данные последовательности возрастают.

Comment: Из кода очевидно, что работает только для возрастающих последовательностей. Можно попробовать переделать, выделяя из глобальных последовательностей возрастающие части, а потом прогоняя через это. Но быстрее, чем спросившим предложенное, точно не будет.
Upd.: ofitserov уже писал почти то же самое)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю отдать должное этой статье: [Длиннейшая возрастающая подпоследовательность за O (N log N)](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log)